# Recursiv table join based on several conditions

Tags: sql, recursion

I have a following audit table in my system:

```
+---+----------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+-----------+
|ID |field           |checkpoint   |value1          |value2                 |created_by |
+---+----------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+-----------+
|1  |active          |0            |null            |1                      |user1      |
|2  |person          |0            |null            |jonh                   |user1      |
|4  |duration        |2            |01.01.1970 0:00 |01.01.1970 0:07        |user1      |
|2  |field_update    |1            |0               |1                      |user2      |
|1  |opened_by       |1            |null            |sam                    |user1      |
|2  |work_note       |2            |null            |TEST                   |user2      |
+---+----------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

Values with the same ID are refer to one entity. This audit table tracks all changes within one entity. So I need to catch following entity: 
when field = 'person' AND value2 = 'john', I need to get next update of this entity (ID). Looking on table it is line 4 (same ID and checkpoint = checkpoint + 1). So we need to count all IDs with mentioned condition by this ID and created_by field.

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
SELECT      *
FROM        mytable a 
INNER JOIN  mytable b ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE       a.field = 'person'
AND         a.value2 = 'john'
AND         b.checkpoint = a.checkpoint + 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly. I need to catch the case when NEXT update after  "field = 'person' AND value2 = 'john' ". Next update is the row where checkpoint of row from table a is -1 comparing to row from table b.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
Select count(id) from audit where id = (select id from audit
group by id 
having count(distinct checkpoint)=max(checkpoint) and min(checkpoint)=1 
where field = 'person' AND value2 = 'john')
```